# How to get the Rank of current row compared to previous rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to get the Rank of current row compared to previous rows

I have a dataframe like:

```
Instru Price Volume
ABCD   1000  100258
ABCD   1000  100252
ABCD   1000  100168
ABCD   1000  100390
ABCD   1000  100470
ABCD   1000  100420
```

I want to get the rank of current row compared to all previous rows for Volume Column.

Desired Dataframe Data:

```
Instru Price Volume  Rank
ABCD   1000  100258  1     => 1st Row so Rank 1
ABCD   1000  100252  2     => Rank 2 (Compare 100258,100252)
ABCD   1000  100168  3     => Rank 3 (Compare 100258,100252,100168)
ABCD   1000  100390  1     => Rank 1 (Compare 100390,100258,100252,100168)
ABCD   1000  100470  1     => Rank 1 (Compare 100470,100390,100258,100252,100168)
ABCD   1000  100420  2     => Rank 2 (Compare 100470,100420,100390,100258,100252,100168)
```

pandas.DataFrame.rank Function doesnot serve my purpose.

Comment: Please elaborate on the ranking function, I can't understand how do you want the ranking to work

Comment: I have edited my desired dataframe for more clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [np.searchsorted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) after a *cumulative sort*:

```
df['Rank'] = np.array([i - np.searchsorted(sorted(df.Volume[:i]), v) for i, v in enumerate(df.Volume)]) + 1
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  Instru  Price  Volume  Rank
0   ABCD   1000  100258     1
1   ABCD   1000  100252     2
2   ABCD   1000  100168     3
3   ABCD   1000  100390     1
4   ABCD   1000  100470     1
5   ABCD   1000  100420     2
```

Comment: How to handle this if there are multiple Instru. I mean how to apply groupby('Instru')

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of the way to use only pandas functions. But computing such rank iteratively is pretty easy:

```
df["rank"] = [df.iloc[0:(i+1)]["Volume"].le(df.iloc[i]["Volume"]).sum() for i in range(len(df))]
```